# multilevel tabcontrol - which collection we use to bindin mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol

I have a wpf application which uses mvvm pattern.

I need to have a collection in my view-model...which i can bind to multi level tab control.

What type of collection I can use in this case ???

Is there any hierarchical collection in C# 3.5 ???

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to bind it to a collection like this

Set context to List < Node >

bind to Node or Nodes

public class Node
{
  public List < Node >  Nodes {get;set;}
}